# Trying to create a m by n matrix using loops in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Again, I am trying to write a function that consumes two natural numbers (m and n) and a string and prints a m by n matrix using the string. For examples

```
my_function(1,5,'hi') => hihih
my_function(2,5,'hi') => hihih
                         ihihi
```

and so on. I have to do this using either for or while loops.

I'm not looking for answers, I'm hoping someone can help me figure it out. 
So far all I can think of is making my string long enough and then using a for loop to break the string onto a new line at the required spot. That is where I encounter my problem. How do I tell python (using for loops) to start my string on a new line at that point.

Hope someone can help.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Since you *have to use loops*, you will find the *modulo* operator useful, this is a partially working solution, I will leave the rest for you to figure out what goes in place of the `?` and the `...`:

```
def my_function(n, m, s):
    ln = ?
    for i in range(n):
        print("".join([s[(j+?) % ln] for ...]))
```

A clue to what modulo is doing:

```
In [98]: l = [1,2,3]

In [99]: l[4 % 3]
Out[99]: 2
```

You can also do it without join once you use print correctly:

```
def my_function(n, m, s):
    ln = ?
    for i in range(n):
        for ...:
            print(s[(j + ?) % ln], end=?)
        # print ?
```

There are nicer ways to do what you want but I presume this is a learning exercise.

Comment: Yeah, I guess they want us to think about the problems a certain way. Its pretty annoying, they will teach us recursion in one module and then the next module theyre like you have to use loops but no recursion. Thanks for your help, i'm working on what you gave me

Answer (score -1):

You don't necessarily need loops. 
Perhaps something like this helps get you started:
 `x=('hi'*5)[:5]`

edit: apologies didn't realize that you *had* to use loops. disregard.